# Is there a good tidy way to turn character columns into ordered factors?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of columns in my data that I want to turn from character into ordered factor. My current solution is this horridly ugly construct, which works but does scald the eyes a bit:

```
load_from_file <- function(filename) {
  d <- read.csv(filename)
  d <- d[,2:37]
  d %<>% na_if("")
  for(column in alwaystonever_questions) {
    eval(parse(text=paste('d$',column,' <- factor(d$',column,', ordered=TRUE,levels=c("Never","Rarely","Sometimes","Often","Always"))',sep="")))
  }
  d$HowAreYouFeeling <- factor(d$HowAreYouFeeling,ordered=TRUE,levels=c("Bad","NotSoGood","Ok","Good","Great"))
  d %<>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)
  return(d)
}
```

I'd like to instead do this in a single slick series of "%>%", which'd hopefully be more readable. How do I do this in a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. It assumes that `alwaystonever_questions` is a character vector. I've left out the `as.factor` part because `factor` should be enough (but if it doesn't work, try it out to add it again, I'm always a bit unsure with factors):

```
library(dplyr)
load_from_file <- function(filename) {
  read.csv(filename) %>% 
    select(2:37) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), na_if, "")) %>% 
    mutate(across(contains(alwaystonever_questions),
           ~factor(.x, ordered = TRUE,
                   levels = c("Never","Rarely","Sometimes","Often","Always"))),
           HowAreYouFeeling = factor(HowAreYouFeeling,
                                     ordered = TRUE,
                                     levels=c("Bad","NotSoGood","Ok","Good","Great")))
}
```

If you have to read in a lot of files, you could do something like:

```
library(purrr)
filenames <- list.files("path_to_directory")

list_dfs <- set_names(filenames) %>% 
  map(load_from_file)
```

Comment: Very nice starja. I was just about to post an almost identical answer. This question is one of the best use cases for `mutate(across(` I have seen. +1

Comment: Thanks, coming from you this means a lot. `across` is indeed very handy once you get used to the new syntax

Comment: When I try to run this code I get the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
i Input `..2` is `~...`.

Comment: @VilhelmAgdur sorry, the brackets for the second `across` were wrong, does it work now?